# "Chains" of Dual Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question

I have seen examples of the following:

1. A sequence of duals extending forever$$S \subset S^*  \subset S^{**}  \subset S^{***} \subset ... \\ S = L^0 $$
2. A sequence of duals flipping between 2 spaces
   $$S \subset S^*  \subset S  \subset S^{*} \subset ... \\ S = L^p $$
3. A sequence of duals which is isometric to itself
   $$S = S^* \\ S = H $$

Are there sequences of duals that "return" every third space or something? Is there some "deep" algebraic fact that these are the only 3 possibilities?